# Запись и чтение вектора (STL vector) объектов, содержащих объекты другого класса, в файл

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

возникла острая необходимость сериализовать и десериализовать вектор в файл, который содержит объекты другого класса. Программа делает все, что нужно, но в конце возвращает следующую ошибку: Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x0126DBD2 в Test_2.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу 0xDDDDDDDD.
 Собственно код:

```
using namespace std;

class A
{

private:

    char name[15];

public:

    A() = default;

    A(char* tmpForName)
    {
        strcpy_s(name, 15, tmpForName);
    }

    ~A() = default;

};

class B
{

private:

    vector<B> dataB;

    A objA;

    char surname[15];

public:

    B() = default;

    B(char* tmpForSurname, char* tmpForName)
    {
        strcpy_s(surname, 15, tmpForSurname);

        objA = A(tmpForName);
    }

    void Add()
    {
        char forName[15], forSurname[15];

        cout << "Enter name: ";

        cin.getline(forName, 15);

        cout << "Enter surname: ";

        cin.getline(forSurname, 15);

        dataB.push_back(B(forSurname, forName));

    }

    void Save(string);

    void Load(string);

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const B&);

};

void B::Save(string fileName)
{

    ofstream out;

    out.open(fileName);

    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dataB), sizeof(dataB));

    out.close();
}

void B::Load(string fileName)
{

    ifstream in;

    in.open(fileName);

    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dataB), sizeof(dataB));

    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dataB), sizeof(dataB));
//...
in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&dataB), sizeof(dataB));
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable

> Objects of trivially-copyable types are the only C++ objects that may be safely copied with std::memcpy or serialized to/from binary files with std::ofstream::write()/std::ifstream::read().

‌‌

> Только объекты тривиальнокопируемых типов в С++ могут безопасно скопироваться с помощью std::memcpy или сериализовываться в/из бинарного файла с помощью std::ofstream::write()/std::ifstream::read()

[Увы:](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8453cd0505fe4e23)

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_trivially_copyable_v<B>; //false
```

Вектор невозможно просто побитово записать в файл, а потом считать. Попробуйте что-то вроде:

```
void B::Save(const std::string &fileName) const
{
    out.open(std::ofstream{fileName});
}
void B::Save(ofstream &out) const
{
    for(const B &b : dataB) {
        b.Save(out);
    }
    out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&objA), sizeof(objA));
    out.write(surname, sizeof(surname));
}
```

Comment: благодарю. Конечный рабочий вариант для моего случая вот такой:                                                                                                      
void B::Save(string fileName)  const
{
 ofstream out;

 out.open(fileName);

 for (const B &b : dataB)
 {
  b.Save(fileName);
 }
 out.write((char*)&objA, sizeof(objA));

 out.write(surname, sizeof(surname));
}`                                                                                                                          Позвольте вопрос: что делает цикл for в Вашем варианте?

Comment: Проходит по всем объектам в векторе предлагает им сохраниться в файл. Только это не полная реализация. Такой файл потом невозможно будет считать, так как неизвестно сколько объектов было записано. Возможно надо было сначала записать размер

Comment: протестировал сейчас написанный код, с учетом Ваших правок: добавил 3 объекта, а потом их считал и вывел на консоль, - все работает. Возможно я ошибаюсь, но такой метод записи в файл не пройдет для остальных контейнеров STL?

Comment: Мне на ум приходит только мап, у котрого придется сохранять еще и значение ключа. Остальные, вроде, можно использовать так же

Comment: такой вопрос: если в классе А я поставлю не char name[15], а string name, то, поскольку string не является POD типом и хранит указатель на ту область в памяти, где находятся мои данные , будет в конце программы вылетать та же ошибка, что я указывал в самом вопросе. Так а можно ли как-то обойти эту проблему? Или же лучше использовать массив символов в таких случаях вместо класса string?

Comment: string сам умеет записываться в поток `out << str`. Правда считать его так опять же не выйдет. `in >> str` считает только первое слово

Comment: я поэтому и говорю, что string , в контексте поля объекта класса не получится считать в файл. Вот и интересуюсь, что тут лучше тогда действовать через создание массива символов вместо string? Или же возможны другие варианты?

Comment: `string` несравноимо удобнее массивов, лучше заморочиться и сериализовать. А вообще, если вы планируете тесно работать с сериализацией посмотрие на специализированне библиотеки.

Comment: еще раз здравствуйте:) Уж прошу прощения за навязчивость, но после того, как Вы посоветовали " лучше заморочиться, но десериализовать string", я как только не пытался это провернуть, но не получилось. Может натолкнете на путь истинный?         http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91c8b59dd46367c4

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c8c5a2a434c632d